# If date between date range

Tags: javascript

I'm working with two dates, e.g. `29/03/2014` and `04/04/2014`, and I have an array of dates e.g. `01/04/2014` and `02/04/2014`, I need to find out how many (if any) dates in that array are between the date range.

What's the best way to do this?

EDIT: Final code, tweaked a little from ponciste's answer

```
//date1 and date2 are the start/end dates
bhDays = new Array();
$.each(DataBridge.bankHolidays, function(i, v) {
    var americanDate = v.split('-'); 
    americanDate = americanDate[1] + '/' + americanDate[0] + '/' + americanDate[2];
    date = new Date(americanDate);
    if (date1 <= date && date2 >= date) {
        bhDays.push(date);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about `Date` objects, or strings in the format you show in the question?

Comment: Create dateObjects for all your dates. Then simply iterate over your array and check if the date is between the limits.

Comment: @nnnnnn They're strings converted to Date Objects. Does the Date object have a method like `addDay(numberOfDays)` where I can increment the number of days, but it keeps track of things like days in month?

Comment: Yes, `.setDate()` sets the day of the month and automatically wraps the month/year as needed, so you can say `someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate()+numDays)` - but you don't need to do that to compare date ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to deal with Date object in this case

so your code should be something like this:

```
var strDateFrom = "29/03/2014";
var strDateTo = "04/04/2014";

var dateFrom = strDateFrom.split("/");
var dateTo = strDateTo.split("/");

var dates = ["01/04/2014", "02/04/2014"];

var from = new Date(dateFrom[2], dateFrom[1]-1, dateFrom[0]);
var to   = new Date(dateTo[2], dateTo[1]-1, dateTo[0]);

dates.forEach(function(date) {
    var dateToCheck = new Date(date[2], date[1]-1, date[0]);
    if(dateToCheck > from && dateToCheck < to)
});
```

Comment: Thanks :), see my answer for the code I used, it's based off this just tweaked a little

Comment: you also used jQuery. Great! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Date object](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html) will do what you want - construct one for each date, then just compare them using the usual operators.

Construct your date objects and compare using < || > operators.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly reccoment to use **moment.js** library for that (and all other operations with date/time) and use [difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function.